# Parallelization of outer loop works in REvolution, but not in normal R

Tags: r, loops, foreach, nested

I am trying to parallelize an outer loop, while running the inner loop sequentially. The following code works in Revolution when using the `doSMP` package, but it does not work in base R when using the `foreach` and `doParallel` packages (both R versions on a Windows machine). The error message is: `could not find function "%do%"`. Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

```
foreach(j = X, .combine = c) %dopar% { 
    Z=1
    foreach(i = Y, .combine = c) %do% { 
        paste(j, i, Z, sep = "") 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if you need to use a package inside a `foreach` loop, you should specify it with the ".packages" option.  That's even true for the `foreach` package itself:

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(j = X, .combine = c, .packages='foreach') %dopar% { 
    Z=1
    foreach(i = Y, .combine = c) %do% { 
        paste(j, i, Z, sep = "") 
    } 
}
```

This makes some sense when you realize that the PSOCK cluster doesn't even know that it's being used by `foreach`.  It's just a normal PSOCK cluster.

Note that it may not be necessary to specify all required packages with some parallel backends. For example, with doMC the workers inherit all currently loaded packages. However, it is good practice to specify them so that the code is more portable.

Comment: Thanks Steve, this help a lot.

Comment: This only applies if the foreach package is not using `parallel` as its backend, right? I didn't have this problem.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander It isn't needed in this case with doMC. But this is a common source of problems on Windows because doMC examples won't work, or when running on a cluster using doSNOW or doMPI.